# Cannot align button beside textbox in a input-group

Tags: c#, html, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I have the following form built using HTML Razor Syntax. I have 3 textboxes horizontally aligned in a single row. The third textbox needs to have a button right beside it. However, the button goes below the textbox. I don't know how to put it beside the textbox.

Here's the HTML code:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Import", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "import" }))
 {    
   <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
     @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CustomerId)
     <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CustomerId, Model.Customers, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "customer" })
     </div>
   </div>

   <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
     @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Order.OrderName, "Order Name")
     <div class="input-group">
       <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
       @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Order.OrderName, new { @class = "form-control", data_rule_validOrder = "true", @id = "order" })
     </div>
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Order.OrderName)
   </div>

   <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
     @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Product.description, "Product")
     <div class="tt-container input-group">
       <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-barcode" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
       @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Product.description, new { @class = "form-control", data_rule_validProduct = "true", @id = "product" })
      </div>

      <span><button type="button" id="addRow" class="btn btn-primary">ADD</button></span>
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Product.description)
   </div>
```

Here's how the textboxes are aligned:

[image]

I want the "ADD" button to show beside the textbox.

**ATTEMPTS: BASED ON DREAMTEK'S ANSWER:**

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-4" style="margin-top:20px">
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Product.description, "Product")
  <div class="tt-container input-group  d-inline-flex">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-barcode" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Product.description, new { @class = "form-control", data_rule_validProduct = "true", @id = "product" })
    <span class="input-group-btn"><button type="button" id="addRow" class="btn btn-primary">ADD</button></span>
  </div>
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Product.description)
</div>
```

I get like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To demonstrate I am showing the markup in this example:

- Move the button inside the local `tt-container`.
- Add class `d-inline-flex` to the button.
- Add class `col` ([flex:1](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#change-2012-flex-continuity)) to each item you wish to stretch.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="form-group col-xs-4">
  Product
  <div class="tt-container input-group d-inline-flex">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-barcode" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    <input type="text" id="product" class="form-control col" />
    <span><button type="button" id="addRow" class="btn btn-primary col">ADD</button></span>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: It didn't work. Please check my update in the question

Comment: @bangbang actually it did work :) You wanted it to appear next to the input and it now does. Now you want also for the items to be automatically adjusted to the available width. See edits above.

Comment: @bangbang It's hard for me to replicate your code exactly without a live example but as you see all you need to need is adjust the wrapper into a flex container and set the items within to be flex elements.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to:

- Add `input-group` to your outer `div`
- Add `input-group-btn` to your `span` of button, like this:

Like this:

```
        //...
        <div class="form-group input-group col-xs-4">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Product.description, "Product")
            <div class="tt-container input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-barcode" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Product.description, new { @class = "form-control", data_rule_validProduct = "true", @id = "product" })
            </div>

            <span class="input-group-btn"><button type="button" id="addRow" class="btn btn-primary">ADD</button></span>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Product.description)
        </div>
```

Comment: This unfortunately did not work for me. The button appeared in the same line as the textbox but very far from the textbox. Plus, the label was misaligned.

Comment: Just add the class="input-group-btn" to the span of button.

Comment: Edited my answer, try it.